# What does the `format()` do in loading data in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am start to use spark and often when loading the data from cloud, I see the following code

```
my_sdf = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter", ' ').load("s3n://myfolder/data/xyz.txt")
```

My question is the following: here it seems that we have 2 data sets: one is the `com.databricks.spark.csv`, as it is a `csv` file right? and another data set is `xyz.txt`, as it is a `txt` file. So in this command, which data set I am loading? I experimented myself, it seems that it is the `xyz.txt` data set is loading. But then my question is what does this `com.databricks.spark.csv` do? Especially it is put in the `format()`. Does it try to tell that spark will load dataset `xyz.txt` using the same format as dataset `com.databricks.spark.csv`?

Answer (score 0):

Form Below Code:-

```
my_sdf = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter", ' ').load("s3n://myfolder/data/xyz.txt")
```

Dataset is `s3n://myfolder/data/xyz.txt`

`Format` is name of format from which you need to read you data set `s3n://myfolder/data/xyz.txt`

`pyspark < 1.6` don't have any `csv format` so `databricks format: com.databricks.spark.csv` is required. If your input data is in any other format like `parquet or orc or json` then you need to use `parquet or orc or json` instead `com.databricks.spark.csv`

> Basically format is structure in which your data is saved.